# variable change only updates when my jquery slider is paused, not when running

Tags: jquery, slider, refresh

I coded a pretty basic jquery slider, I have a seconds variable which I use to customize the seconds it takes to switch between images. My problem is changing the seconds only takes effect when the slider is running (pause button not clicked), I would like itto instantly update instead of having to pause the slider, change the seconds variable and hitting play again.

How could I approach this, I feel like it's a fairly easy task but I am kind of a js newbie.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var segundos = 3000;
  var stop = true;
  var slideInterval;


  $('.play').click(function() {
    if (stop == false) {
      stop = true;
      $('#playpause').text('Play it');
      clearInterval(slideInterval);
    } else {
      stop = false;
      $('#playpause').text('Pause it');
      slideInterval = setInterval(swapSlides, segundos);
    }
  });


  function swapSlides() {
    //var cs = $('div.currentslide:first');
    var cs = $('#polaroid1').children('.currentslide:first');
    var ns = cs.next();
    if (ns.hasClass('mySlides1')) {
      cs.removeClass('currentslide');
      ns.addClass('currentslide');
    } else {
      ns = $('#polaroid1').children('div.mySlides1:first');
      cs.removeClass('currentslide');
      ns.addClass('currentslide');
    }
  }


  $('.resta').click(function() {
    if (segundos > 1000) {
      segundos = segundos - 1000;
      segundoss = (segundos / 1000);
      $('.segundos').text(" " + segundoss + "s ");
    }
  });

  $('.suma').click(function() {
    if (segundos >= 1000 && segundos < 15000) {
      segundos = segundos + 1000;
      segundoss = (segundos / 1000);
      $('.segundos').text(" " + segundoss + "s ");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.menu {
  list-style: none;
  bottom: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 200px;
}

.menu>li {}

.play {
  width: 59px;
  height: 52px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.polaroid1 {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 380px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.photo1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
}

.date1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  font-size: 28px;
}

.mySlides1 {
  display: none;
  width: 380px;
  height: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.currentslide {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu hide">
  <li style="font-size:22px; margin-top:8px;">Diapositivas: <span class="resta" style="cursor:pointer;">< </span><span class="segundos">3s</span><span class="suma" style="cursor:pointer;"> ></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="polaroid1" class="polaroid1">
  <div class="tooltip2 play" style="background-image: url('images/heart2.png');"><span id="playpause" class="tooltiptext2">Play it</span></div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade currentslide">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/IMG-20170610-WA0028.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170812_181516.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">12-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170522_112958.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/IMG-20170610-WA0017.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">10-06-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170819_194526.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">19-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170811_182103.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">11-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170522_124602.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170419_020725.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">19-04-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170520_115819.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">20-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170822_011703.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170705_184344.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">05-07-2017</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your Code is not working and also question is not clear, what is your desired output

Comment: Weird, its working for me. Basically I want the segundos variable to automatically change each time the .resta o .suma classes are clicked, it actually changes but the slider has to be paused. I want it to automatically change even when the slider is playing

Comment: @gabogabans so it's a duplicate.. I answered your question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445648/my-jquery-slider-refresh-rate-wont-update-live/47446545#47446545

Answer (score 0):

See below if this is what you want

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var segundos = 3000;
  var stop = true;
  var slideInterval;


  $('.play').click(function() {
    if (stop == false) {
      stop = true;
      $('#playpause').text('Play it');
      clearInterval(slideInterval);
    } else {
      stop = false;
      $('#playpause').text('Pause it');
      slideInterval = setInterval(swapSlides, segundos);

    }
  });


  function swapSlides() {
    //var cs = $('div.currentslide:first');
    var cs = $('#polaroid1').children('.currentslide:first');
    var ns = cs.next();
    if (ns.hasClass('mySlides1')) {
      cs.removeClass('currentslide');
      ns.addClass('currentslide');
      if (segundos >= 1000 && segundos < 15000) {
        segundos = segundos + 1000;
        segundoss = (segundos / 1000);
        $('.segundos').text(" " + segundoss + "s ");
      }
    } else {
      ns = $('#polaroid1').children('div.mySlides1:first');
      cs.removeClass('currentslide');
      ns.addClass('currentslide');
      if (segundos > 1000) {
        segundos = segundos - 1000;
        segundoss = (segundos / 1000);
        $('.segundos').text(" " + segundoss + "s ");
      }
    }
  }


  $('.resta').click(function() {
    if (segundos > 1000) {
      segundos = segundos - 1000;
      segundoss = (segundos / 1000);
      $('.segundos').text(" " + segundoss + "s ");
    }
  });

  $('.suma').click(function() {
    if (segundos >= 1000 && segundos < 15000) {
      segundos = segundos + 1000;
      segundoss = (segundos / 1000);
      $('.segundos').text(" " + segundoss + "s ");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.menu {
  list-style: none;
  bottom: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 200px;
}

.menu>li {}

.play {
  width: 59px;
  height: 52px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.polaroid1 {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 380px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.photo1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
}

.date1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  font-size: 28px;
}

.mySlides1 {
  display: none;
  width: 380px;
  height: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.currentslide {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu hide">
  <li style="font-size:22px; margin-top:8px;">Diapositivas: <span class="resta" style="cursor:pointer;">&lt; </span>
    <span class="segundos">3s</span>
    <span class="suma" style="cursor:pointer;"> &gt;</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="polaroid1" class="polaroid1">
  <div class="tooltip2 play" style="background-image: url('images/heart2.png');"><span id="playpause" class="tooltiptext2">Play it</span></div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade currentslide">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/IMG-20170610-WA0028.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170812_181516.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">12-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170522_112958.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/IMG-20170610-WA0017.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">10-06-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170819_194526.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">19-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170811_182103.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">11-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170522_124602.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170419_020725.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">19-04-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170520_115819.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">20-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170822_011703.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170705_184344.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">05-07-2017</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really, segundos value has to be changed via the .resta and .suma classes being clicked, this already works. Problem is the new values only take effect if the slider is paused when segundos change.

Comment: have you seen the code snippet in fullscreen isn't it changing the segundos value when you start auto play? and if i am correct `segundos` means `seconds` and `resta` means `remaining`

Comment: resta means substracts, as in when resta is clicked I substract 1 second to segunos whicj means seconds yes, I am from Spain hehe my problem basically is I want the slider to reflect segundos even when the slider is playing, currently the changes only take action if the slider is paused when segundos change vi.resta or .suma

Comment: i just verified again the slider is changing the values when i click autoplay, either i am not getting what you actually want .